# Best practices for blitting in flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am creating a blit game and as of right now, the only thing that is blitting is the world itself (i.e. roads, fences). i was planning on displaying my character as a sprite and any interactive objects that it comes by as sprites as well. PickUps, Houses, Enemies. I was wanting to know what are the best practices when it comes to this. does this seem wise. When normallying blitting a game, how much of the game is actual blit, and how much should be display objects.

Comment: Is your blit content just images loaded, or are they movieclips (sprites) that are being drawn onto a bitmap?

Comment: they are images. I figured what I would probably do is set the area of the game that is constantly changing and beign redrawn (ground, trees) to be blit, the rest that require animation such as people, I will use as sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now i think the best thing to do is set the area of the game that is constantly changing and beign redrawn (ground, trees) to be blit, the rest that require animation such as people, I will use as sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this site? http://www.8bitrocket.com/

It should answer any questions about blitting and standards.

Comment: Yes, i have been there. I havnt seen any standards on blitting. Only history, and how to use them.